# Chef recipes - use node name in attributes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

In a chef recipe I have the following code:

```
if (node['server1']['PT1'] == true)
   setup('PT1')
elsif (node['server1']['PT2'] == true)
   setup('PT2')
end
```

I am checking my attributes to see if the value equals true for either PT1 or PT2. This works correctly if i hardcode `server1` into the code but I want to know do it dynamically depending on the server running this. How would I replace `node['server1']` with something like `node.name` to find different servers in the attribute file. An example of my attributes is:

```
default['server1'][...]...
default['server2'][...]...
default['server3'][...]...
default['server4'][...]...
```

If I can dynamically look at the different servers, that'd be the ideal result.

Comment: What's an example value of `node`, which class of object?

Comment: Sorry, my attributes start with `default` not `node`. I plan on having the different sever names being the first part of the attribute where you see `server1, server2, etc`. The plan is to pass in the server name and match it with the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this totally dynamic even:

```
node['whatever'][node.name].each do |key, value|
  setup(key) if value == true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your naming convention. It doesn't look like ohai gathers the node name information automatically but it does gather up a lot of information.

If you have a standard around your node names, such as using their hostname or fqdn as the node name, then you can simply query for that.

`node['hostname']...
node['fqdn']...`

If you use a more esoteric method to name your nodes that have nothing to do with your host information you can still query the client.rb located on your node, which is how your node knows what to identify itself as to the Chef server. On windows it's located at `C:/chef/client.rb`, on UNIX its at `/etc/chef/client.rb`. I'll leave the parsing of the file up to you.

To view the full extent of what ohai (everything available under `node`) log onto a bootstrapped machine and type `ohai` into your shell. Its quite a bit so you might want to output to a text file and use an editor to scroll/search through it.

EDIT1:
In test kitchen the location changes. It becomes `<your kitchen cache location>\client.rb>` EX, if you use vagrant with windows and its defaults it becomes `c:\users\vagrant\appdata\local\temp\kitchen\client.rb`

EDIT2:
To bring it back to your original example, if the contents of your node['server'] can either be PT1 or PT2 then you can do the following

`setup(node['server'])`

and you can control the contents of what server is through any variety of mechanisms. If you are controlling it through hostname then you could do

`attributes/default.rb
...
node['server']= node['hostname']`

or more simply, if your standards are such that allow for it

`recipes/default.rb
...
setup(node['hostname'])`

Although normally you'd control what is being setup in separate recipes defined in your runlist.

Comment: I can change it to the identical hostname if need be. So if I do, `node['hostname'][PT1]` in my recipe, it would find the attribute `default['server1']['PT1]` if the hostname is `server1`? I thought it would look for an actual attribute starting in `default['hostname']` and not convert it.

Comment: Editting to match your edit: node['hostname'] returns the hostname of the current server Chef is running on. It would return 'server1' if your hostname is server1, and the identical code on server2 would return 'server2'. ohai is only aware of its current node.